# Razor markup returning some elements on one line and others on same line with no whitespace

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have this snippet in a .chtml file

```
<div id="commandbuttons" class="well-sm">
@Html.ActionLink("Back to Audits", "Index", "Audits", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
@Html.ActionLink("Edit the Audit", "Edit", "Audits", new { id = Model.Audit.AuditID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })   
@if (@ViewBag.IsAdmin)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete the Audit", "Delete", "Audits", new { id = Model.Audit.AuditID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Assign Claims", "AssignClaims", "Audits", new { id = Model.Audit.AuditID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" }) 
    @Html.ActionLink("Assign Credits", "AssignCredits", "Audits", new { id = Model.Audit.AuditID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" }) 
    @Html.ActionLink("Assign Matches", "AssignMatches", "Audits", new { id = Model.Audit.AuditID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" }) 
    @Html.ActionLink("Assign Vendors", "AssignVendors", "Audits", new { id = Model.Audit.AuditID }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })    
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="@ViewBag.Link">Request Statements</a>
}
```

Can any one explain to me why my HTML output looks like this?

```
<div id="commandbuttons" class="well-sm">
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Audits/Index">Back to Audits</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Audits/Edit/23">Edit the Audit</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Audits/Delete/23">Delete the Audit</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Audits/AssignClaims/23">Assign Claims</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Audits/AssignCredits/23">Assign Credits</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Audits/AssignMatches/23">Assign Matches</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="/Audits/AssignVendors/23">Assign Vendors</a>        <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://fileserver.ams-par.local/APApps/RequestMailer/RequestMailer.application?auditID=23">Request Statements</a>
```

Why are the elements in the if statement returned on a single line where the elements created before the if statement are on separate lines?  I know this really should not make a differences in the result but it seems to be creating spaces between the buttons that get created when on separate lines and the buttons are together when on the same line.  I hope I am explaining this correctly and clear enough for someone to understand.